# How to log query being executed by Yii CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii

Is there any way to see the query being executed by a CDbCriteria?

Comment: You have tagged both Yii and Yii2. Which one is it? Please provide the code on how you call the query because CDbCriteria does not execute a query at all

Comment: CDbCriteria is related with Yii1 only.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use this in my config file `protected/config/main.php`

```
// SQL Commands
array(
  'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
    'maxFileSize' => 30720,
    'maxLogFiles' => 10,
    'rotateByCopy' => true,
  'levels'=>'trace,info,error,warning',
  'logFile'=>'sql.log',
  'categories'=>'system.db.CDbCommand'
),
```

Reference:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging

Notice `categories` index: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogRoute#categories-detail

> array of categories, or string list separated by comma or space.
>   Defaults to empty array, meaning all categories.

`CDbCriteria` doesn't execute queries itself, it is passed to other classes like `CActiveDataProvider` or methods like `find()`, etc which calls `CDbCommand` in the end. So we log only that category.

I am not that good with terminology, hope you got it.